# DirectShowPlayerService::doRender: Unresolved error code 0x80040266 (IDispatch error #102)

Tags: qt, gstreamer

I am trying to stream a video over tcp based on gstreamer daemon.
I have created a pipeline which streams video over tcp socket as below:

```
pipeline_create p  videotestsrc is-live=true pattern="ball" ! x264enc ! queue ! mpegtsmux ! tcpserversink host=0.0.0.0 port=12345
```

Now I am designing a Video player application in Qt, which will receive the above video stream and play it.The code is as below

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include<QMediaPlayer>
#include<QVideoWidget>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    //Dialog w;
    //w.show();
    QMediaPlayer *player=new QMediaPlayer;
    QVideoWidget *vw=new QVideoWidget;
    player->setVideoOutput(vw);
    QUrl *url=new QUrl("http://127.0.0.1:12345");
    QMediaContent *mc=new QMediaContent(*url);
    player->setMedia(*mc);
    vw->setGeometry(100,100,300,400);
    vw->show();
    player->play();
    qDebug()<<player->state();
    return a.exec();
}
```

At first when I got the error code 0x80040266, I Installed [K-lite codec](https://www.codecguide.com/download_kl.htm) and [LAV Filters](http://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?t=156191) and after that only for the first time my video player was able to stream and play the video as shown.

But then, when I again try to play my video player, it shows below error

```
DirectShowPlayerService::doRender: Unresolved error code 0x80040266 (IDispatch error #102)
```

Can anyone guide me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Download K-Lite Codec Pack and install on your system may be it will be solve your error